# When I'm texting, sometimes the receiver's email shows up

Tags: ios, messages, contacts

Whenever I start a text, my contacts list shows email addresses instead of phone numbers.  Not always but very often. Sometimes a contact will be that way, then next time it won't.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent!  So, specifically, what is your question?  "Why is this happening?" Or, "Is there some way to change the settings?" or just curious?

Comment: Yes why? And how can it default to thephone number.

Answer (score 1):

Those emails are from iMessage, as you can receive iMessages with both your email and phone number. If the messages are colored blue, it is iMessage.

https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_06_20_stop_sending_imessage_from_email/

Comment: Hmm. Its weird cause for the same person, sometimes its the email and sometimes its their number.  But thanks